# Devise forgot password not showing error of user not found in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have a rails app deployed in heroku.

I'm using devise for user authentication and in development, if a user uses the Forgot Password feature and inputs a email that doesn't exist in the DB, a message of User not found is displayed.

But in production (heroku), in the same situation, the error message is not shown, and only display that there was an error and if you're the owner of the app you should check the logs.

I've checked the logs and they show the following messages:

```
2023-03-30T19:47:06.256967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/password/new" host=app.orbochile.com request_id=734420d1-6af7-4b37-b069-8e6555c82767 fwd="138.84.34.152" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=8117 protocol=https
2023-03-30T19:47:18.757588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/password" host=app.orbochile.com request_id=15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46 fwd="138.84.34.152" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=42ms status=500 bytes=1861 protocol=https
2023-03-30T19:47:18.722934+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-03-30T19:47:18.722857 #2]  INFO -- : [15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46] Started POST "/users/password" for 138.84.34.152 at 2023-03-30 19:47:18 +0000
2023-03-30T19:47:18.723930+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-03-30T19:47:18.723857 #2]  INFO -- : [15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46] Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
2023-03-30T19:47:18.743950+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-03-30T19:47:18.743840 #2]  INFO -- : [15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"probjando@cualquiercosa.cl"}, "commit"=>"Enviarme instrucciones para recuperar clave"}
2023-03-30T19:47:18.756464+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-03-30T19:47:18.756373 #2]  INFO -- : [15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms | Allocations: 4392)
2023-03-30T19:47:18.757351+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2023-03-30T19:47:18.757289 #2] FATAL -- : [15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46]   
2023-03-30T19:47:18.757353+00:00 app[web.1]: [15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46] NameError (undefined local variable or method `rendering_options' for #<TurboDeviseController::Responder:0x0000563f5a84d808 @controller=#<Devise::PasswordsController:0x0000000001ff40>, @request=#<ActionDispatch::Request POST "https://app.orbochile.com/users/password" for 138.84.34.152>, @format=:turbo_stream, @resource=#<User id: nil, email: "probjando@cualquiercosa.cl", name: nil, nick_name: nil, phone: nil, city: nil, state: nil, dob: nil, gender: nil, admin: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, category: "Estándar", age: 0, ages: "S/R", last_name: nil, superadmin: false, tester: false, type_user: "Usuario regular">, @resources=[#<User id: nil, email: "probjando@cualquiercosa.cl", name: nil, nick_name: nil, phone: nil, city: nil, state: nil, dob: nil, gender: nil, admin: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, category: "Estándar", age: 0, ages: "S/R", last_name: nil, superadmin: false, tester: false, type_user: "Usuario regular">], @options={}, @action=:new, @default_response=nil>):
2023-03-30T19:47:18.757353+00:00 app[web.1]: [15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46]   
2023-03-30T19:47:18.757354+00:00 app[web.1]: [15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46] app/controllers/turbo_devise_controller.rb:9:in `rescue in to_turbo_stream'
2023-03-30T19:47:18.757355+00:00 app[web.1]: [15f2ef52-0b2e-4ec9-aeb7-1dcfac86ea46] app/controllers/turbo_devise_controller.rb:3:in `to_turbo_stream'
```

I understand that in the last lines it says that there's an errow because there no matching user with the email, but I don't know how to make the view to show the error message for the user, instead of showing the message that the app is not working.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I need in this situation for the User Not Found error to be displayed instead of that information of checking the logs.

EDIT

```
<h2 class="titulo">¿Olvidaste tu clave?</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Enviarme instrucciones para recuperar clave", class:"btn", id:"boton" %>
  </div>
  
<% end %>
```

That's my new password view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack overflow.

There's a very good reason why Devise does not show "user not found' to users in production.
The reason is, that if you show that - then a malicious user can figure out what users already exist in your production database by throwing a whole bunch of common usernames at it, and seeing which match a real user and which don't.

I can strongly recommend that you do not update your system to give out the information that you are asking for.
This is serious information leakage and is very much frowned upon, which is why devise does not show that to the user.

The common alternative instead is to say "either the username or password do not match, try again" and the user will just try again.